# Editing css on specific category

Tags: html, css, categories

I have a list of categories and each category has its own label and icon on my homepage.  Each category label/icon should be a unique colour.

This is easy via HTML:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: category in categories | orderBy:'display_priority' --> 
<a ng-href="explore?category=53" ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy:
'display_priority'" class="ui random-color item large label ng-binding ng-scope" 
ng-show="hasCategory" href="explore?category=53" style="color:red";>
```

The UI is under development and this HTML is wiped with each UI update (regularly).  Therefore, I am trying to achieve the same result via CSS.

I can change the colour of the category labels generically (i.e. make them all the same colour) with this code:

```
#front-page .ui.label {
color: #XYZ
}
```

Is it possible for me to change the colour of each label individually purely via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of categories is limited then you could use a set of CSS3 nth-child pseudo classes to do this:

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/understanding-nth-child-pseudo-class-expressions/

You could also do this dynamically with JavaScript by enumerating the category DOM elements in a loop and then setting the css color of the element.

Comment: Thank you, the nth-child pseudo classes looks like a possible solution, I am looking into it.